# Taylor Expanding an Integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

Just want to be sure of this: If I taylor expand an integrand about 0 then truncate it to say linear order, then integrate this truncation, does the integral evaluate to a function which is an accurate representation of the original integral, but only around 0? If so why is this?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm actually sure now that I can - the area under the functions will be the same about 0. Sorry just wanted to make sure I was right about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "accurate" and "around 0."

Assuming sufficient smoothness of $f$, Taylor's theorem states that for every $h$,

$$f(h) = f(0) + h f'(0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(c)$$
for some $c\in [0,h]$. Suppose your integral is from $0$ to $a$ and you have a bound $f''(x) < M$ on $[0,a]$. Call $g(x) = f(0)+xf'(0)$ your truncated function. Then

$$\left|\int_0^a g(x)\, dx - \int_0^a f(x)\, dx\right|\leq \int_0^a \left|f(x)-g(x)\right|\,dx \leq \int_0^a \frac{x^2}{2}M = \frac{a^3}{6}M.$$

Whether or not this error is important will depend on $a$ and $M$.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor theorem says (I skip the hypothesis): $$f(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f'(\xi)}{2}x^2.$$ The point is that $\xi$ depends on $x$ and in general this dependance is very nasty. You can integrate both parts of the equation with respect to $x$ on some interval, but I don't think you can get something useful from the right side representation other than approximations of the integral.